# Wordpress plugin check for update from server

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a plugin for Wordpress right now, and want it to be able to update the software to the latest version on the Wordpress extensions gallery when it does go up there eventually. There seems to be little or no code about how to do that. What's more is that the plugin generates a text file to keep a couple of basic things in memory after first run, and I don't want to lose that on update.

How do I ensure these two things can happen?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for users to detect any new Plugin Updates, you'll need to read up on the [Wordpress Plugin Developer Center Documentation](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/).

Assuming that your Plugin is accepted, it will be hosted on Wordpress' [Subversion Repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/svn/) and will be available to anybody who would like to download it, and will also be available to you to update at your leisure. Once new updates are detected, users that are utilizing your plugin will be automatically notified by Wordpress in the Plugin Menu that there is a new update available.

As far as your text file is concerned, you will need to also read the [Plugin Guidelines](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/guidelines/) to make sure you aren't violating any of their terms. Otherwise, your plugin will be denied from their hosting platform.

If your plugin is greenlit for hosting and you still need a solution to your txt file problem, then you have a few options to store the data:

1. You can store the file outside of your plugin's directory (ie: the
   root of the Wordpress Install, or the Plugin directory itself). Bear
   in mind, you will also probably be required to hook into Wordpress'
   [deactivate_(plugin
   file name) Action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) to clean up any files that are no longer
   required/wanted by the user.
2. It would probably be best to store the plugin data you need in a
       separate table (and subsequently deleted upon deactivation) that you
       can query at any time. You can also use [Custom Options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages) if you don't want to use a separate table.

Hopefully, this is enough information to get you started on your plugin. Let me know if this helps.